# Are namespaces taken into account when contacting a soap web service?

Tags: c#, xml, soap, namespaces

I have some existing code which uses a third party SOAP client to retrieve data from another third party web service. As we switched to a new data provider, we also switched to their new endpoint. We found out that our current requests are all failing and the error we get in return is "Policy Falsified".

I have used SOAP UI to test the new web service and I can successfully obtain data this way. That is why I compared the two soap messages and found out that the problem is likely with the URI used for the soap namespace.

```xml
Code generated soap message
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
    <s:Body xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
        <Request>
            //...
        </Request>
    </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>

Working message with SOAP UI
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <soap:Body xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
        <Request>
            //...
        </Request>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

The only differences in these messages are the namespace prefixes and the soap namespace (the data inside the request tag are identical). I would like to know if this web service is rejecting my soap message purely by the soap namespace that it's using, or that something else might play a problem?

Obviously I am likely going to need to make my own implementation to generate the soap messages myself, but I'd still like to know if the webservice is set to only accept messages with that specific soap namespace or that it's some other kind of issue?

Comment: I think you have already determined the answer empirically, which is the best way. You will have to inquire with the service provider to figure out why. They could have created a bug; they might have *fixed* a bug; they may have purposefully broken compatibility; or they may have introduced an XML firewall, to name a few possibilities.

Comment: The differences in the two soap is they are using different schema.  The 2003/05 schema is failing.